# Pass all HTML table values to PHP to store them in database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have an HTML table which I populate from database using a button. I want to get all the values from the table and send them to a php file to store each row in the database using Javascript when a button is clicked.
I thought of using a SESSION variable instead of javascript in order to do this but I am not sure this is the best way to do it and I have no idea where to start.

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

this is the table code if it helps:

```
<table id="dgvDetalleFactura" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" width="60%" cellspacing="0" data-toggle="bootgrid">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-column-id="IDProducto" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Código</th><!--Editable-->
                                <th data-column-id="NombreProducto">Producto</th>
                                <th data-column-id="Cantidad">Cantidad</th> <!--Editable-->
                                <th data-column-id="Precio">Precio</th><!--Editable-->
                                <th data-column-id="UnidadMedida">Medida</th>
                                <th data-column-id="Impuesto">Imp.</th>
                                <th data-column-id="Descuento">Desc.</th> <!--Editable-->
                                <th data-column-id="Total">Total</th>
                                <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Opciones</th> <!--Columna de acciones de borrado-->
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Why are you taking data out of a database to stick into an html table and then taking that same data and sticking it back into a database again?

Comment: JavaScript runs on the clients computer and can't access the servers database

Comment: @dmikester1 is not the same data, I am working on an invoice system and I trying to store the invoice product list

Comment: @Andreas I know what you mean but I am just looking for a way to pass the data to PHP using javascript

Comment: @Errol, you can convert to a json object. -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602443/converting-table-data-into-json

Comment: Use something like Axios or jQuery to post the data? https://codingthesmartway.com/getting-started-with-axios/

Comment: Or for jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code that ended up working for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function GrabarFila()
{
    var dgvDetalleFactura = document.getElementById('dgvDetalleFactura');

    var TableData = new Array();

    $('#dgvDetalleFactura tr').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData[row]={
            "IDProducto" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
            , "NombreProducto" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
            , "Cantidad" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
            , "PrecioVentaSinIV" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
            , "UnidadMedida" : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text()
            , "ImpuestoVentas" : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text()
            , "Descuento" : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
            , "TotalNeto" : $(tr).find('td:eq(15)').text()
        }
    }); 
    TableData.shift();

    $.ajax({
            url: 'Logica/Factura.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 
            {
               DetalleFactura:TableData,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){

                var len = response.length;

                if(len > 0){

                alert("Exito");

                }

            }
        });

        return false;
}   

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach if you are allowing the user to update the table and wanting to save the data on-the-fly is to set up an api on the server side that receives the data via POST either as multiple parameters or or a single JSON object and then passes that data to the server via an Ajax call.  JQuery has a good component for making Ajax calls easy.

This is all very straight-forward and fundamental functioning and things you should learn to do in any case but your learning curve is likely to be pretty steep.  I won't go into details on all of the steps (it would take pages) but here are the broad strokes and techniques required.  Let's assume you will use JSON

1. Create a JS on your client side to read the data from your table
   via the DOM (Jquery/JS/DOM)
2. Encapsulate that data into a single
   codable object for transfer to the server (JSON)
3. Implement a server side script that can receive that object, decode it and save
   it to your new database (PHP/POST/GET/JSON/MYSQL)
4. Implement JS on the client side to interface with that new PHP script and deliver the JSON data from the client to the server (Ajax/Jquery/POST/GET)
5. As an extra, have the PHP API return a code of "success" or "failure" upon receipt of the data and display that on the client side (PHP/Jquery/DOM)

Those are the "broad strokes" of what you'll need to research.