# Transform data from API into JSON format in REACT

Tags: reactjs, json, formatting

I would like to display data from the API to the front-end. To do so, I have an API running and a React Front-end accessing the API.
The front-end can access the data but the data are not in a shape I would like :
[image]

Indeed, I would like a JSON format in order to display this values in a nice table in the front-end.

Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

Thank you in advance for your help,
Alexia

Comment: You can use JSON.parse(data) to convert your data into JS object.
If you want to convert your data into JSON, you can use JSON.stringify() method.

Comment: With JSON.stringify(), I got :

Comment: `"         Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits\n0  2022-02-03  882.000000  937.000000  880.520020  891.140015  891.140015  26285200          0             0\n1  2022-02-04  897.219971  936.500000  881.169983  923.320007  923.320007  24472600          0             0...`

Comment: ok. Now what you can do is convert your columns into arrays and convert them into string. I don't know it will work or not ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602443/converting-table-data-into-json
check out this post it might help you.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to convert jquery into react code

Comment: Can you help me with the conversion? I am struggling